# Send constant values to the Alfresco activiti processes

Tags: spring, alfresco

I am using alfresco in my spring application and I am sending constants values to alfresco process by using two different ways. 
1.By using alfresco method like runtimeService.setVariable("key","value"). 
2.Sending through map at the time of start process instance. 
  Now my problem is I want to send 250 values to the process and those values will be used for all processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. store your constants in a properties file
2. Load it in properties object
3. Convert the properties object to a Map object
4. finally, use the second way to send it to your process